# steghide: the file format of the file "filename.jpg" is not supported

Tags: linux, kali-linux, steganography

I am trying to get data from an image, but first I want to check if the image is actually containts data.
I tried to user 'steghide' to extract data from it but i got this error :

```
steghide: the file format of the file "Summmmmmmer.jpg" is not supported
```

This is the command i was using :

```
$ steghide extract -sf Summmmmmmer.jpg  -p <password> -xf result.txt
```

This is the file itself :

[image]

***(Postscript)***
I also tried to use Summmmmmmer.png, It didn't worked too.
Thanks for help !

Comment: The error seems pretty clear!

Comment: Yeah well iv'e tried to fix it by changing the file format but it didn't help.

Comment: What's the _actual_ format of those files? Sure it claims to be a .jpg file, but does it actually have JPEG data inside? Run `file Summer.jpg` and check.